# Excel macro : compare cell value with external filename/folder content

Tags: excel, vba

I need to complete this code, can you help me?
I have to use it inside an Excel macro.This macro have to check if what is written in each cell (inside them there are song names) is present in a specific folder in the form of files. For example if in a cell there is "Nothing Else Matter", the script will have to check if in that folder there is a file with that name. This is a script that should allow me to save time, I apologize for the errors but it is the first time I put my hand to this language (not my work, I say it for fairness).

The error that comes out is as follows:

> Compilation error:
>
> Syntax error

The problem is on the line with "*If Dir(songname)  "" Then*"

```
Sub Test_if_File_exists_in_dir()

Dim RangeOfCells As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim songname As String

Dim TotalRow As Long

TotalRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set RangeOfCells = Range("A2:A" & TotalRow)

For Each Cell In RangeOfCells
    songname = "C:\Alessio\Songs\" & Cell & ".*"

        If Dir(songname)  "" Then 
            Cell.Font.Color = vbRed
        Else
            Cell.Font.Color = vbBlack
        End If

Next Cell
MsgBox "Done, verify data first time"

End Sub
```

Thank you,

Alessio

Comment: "It has to verify the content of every cell is present in a folder as a file" This sentence makes no sense. `Cells` are in `worksheets`, which themselves are in `workbooks` that can be saved as `files` in `folders`. Can you please [edit your question to clarify it. Including the exact error message and the line of code that triggers it would be useful. A more specific title would also be a good thing

Comment: `If Dir(songnme) "" Then` is missing an operator. `=` for equality, `<>` for inequality. I'm guessing that meant to be `If Dir(songname) <> "" Then`.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I tried adding "<>" and it don't give any errors but the script doesn't work (if I add "<>", it change color if is not present or otherwise?). If I explain it better, can you help to understand why it doesn't work? Thank you

(This is the screen of the [Excel file](https://ibb.co/9yZ9xGW) where I have the list of the songs while this is the [folder](https://ibb.co/mBs7203) where the script has to check if the songs are present or not) Thank you again.

Comment: credit where credit is due, @MathieuGuindon is the one who suggested using `<>` **or** `=`, what happens if you try `=`?

Comment: I was mentioning both of you, but I think I deleted his name by mistake (Sorry Mathieu!). In any case, I would like to thank you both for your time. However, if I try to put = instead of <> all the titles are marked in red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test_if_File_exists_in_dir()

    Dim RangeOfCells As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim songname As String

    Dim TotalRow As Long

    TotalRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set RangeOfCells = Range("A2:A" & TotalRow)

    For Each Cell In RangeOfCells
        'edit: include artist
        songname = "C:\Alessio\Songs\" & _
                    Cell.Offset(0, 1) & " - " & Cell & ".*"
        Debug.print "Checking: " & songname
        Cell.Font.Color = IIf(Len( Dir(songname) ) = 0, vbRed, vbBlack)

    Next Cell
    MsgBox "Done, verify data first time"

End Sub
```

Comment: I tested it, it works but Excel give me an error message (run-time error 52: Invalid file name or number) about `Cell.Font.Color = IIf(Len(Dir(songname)) = 0, vbRed, vbBlack)`. Can be a problem? Another thing, I have in the column A the name of the song and in the column B the name of the artist (as you can see [here](https://ibb.co/9yZ9xGW)). This code compare only the value of the cell with the title. Is it possible to verify both name of the song and name of the artist? (for example it verify if A2+B2 is present inside the folder). I ask this because it cause lot of false positive.Thank you

Comment: Ok it worked until row 68, from 69 to 498 it doesn't checked. Which is the cause?

Comment: Edited above to include the artist - you might need to tweak that for a better match (eg add in a wildcard or two) if it still has issues

Comment: It works perfectly for the artist! Instead it still appear the message error about the portion of code quoted before (`Cell.Font.Color = IIf(Len(Dir(songname)) = 0, vbRed, vbBlack)`). It checks firsts 169 row and then ignore the other 331 row. Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: Solved! One artist (Format:B) has inside the name a special character (:) that can't be used. Thanks again for the help!